# why is the size method of MultiMap from Guava return (un)expected result?

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I am using `MultiMap` from `Guava` library. I created a sample MultiMap. when I print the size of map, I get `4` but the actual value (I think) should be 2. why is this discrepancy?

```
   import java.util.Collection;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class MultiMapTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
  Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

  // Adding some key/value
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Bannana");
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Apple");
  myMultimap.put("Fruits", "Pear");
  myMultimap.put("Vegetables", "Carrot");

  System.out.println(myMultimap);

  // Getting the size
  int size = myMultimap.size();
  System.out.println(size);  // 4

  // Getting values
  Collection<String> fruits = myMultimap.get("Fruits");
  System.out.println(fruits); // [Bannana, Apple, Pear]

  Collection<String> vegetables = myMultimap.get("Vegetables");
  System.out.println(vegetables); // [Carrot]

 }
}
```

Output:

```
Fruits=[Bannana, Apple, Pear], Vegetables=[Carrot]}
4
[Bannana, Apple, Pear]
[Carrot]
```

Here is the output:

From the [ArrayListMultiMap docs](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#size%28%29), this should return the number of key-value pairs in the multimap. But I don't see it.

Comment: You `put()` 4 things in and are surprised when it says it contains 4 items? Key-Value Pair 1 `Fruit-Bananna` 2 `Fruit-Apple` 3 `Fruit-Pear` 4 `Vegetables-Carrot`.

Comment: so the 4 is number of the values from it. In a regular map, size gives the size based on keys. so I was assuming the same and the docs weren't clear to me

Comment: @brainstorm: `Map` also defines `size()` as `the number of key-value mappings in this map`. It just happens that since each key has exactly one value, that's also equal to the number of keys and the number of values.

Comment: @ColinD: Not sure if I get that. what do you mean by each key has exactly one value? even in MultiMap each key has exactly one value (and that value happens to be list here)

Comment: @brainstorm: Please read the [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) Javadoc. A `Multimap` is _not_ a `Map`! It can be _viewed_ as a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, but conceptually it is in fact a data structure that can map the same key to multiple different values. See also the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) on multimaps.

Comment: And by "each key has exactly one value", I mean just that: a `Map` is something which maps keys to one value each, thus `size()` == `entrySet().size()` == `keySet().size()` == `values().size()` always.

Comment: @ColinD:Thanks for the clarification. In Map from Java.util, I can have Map<K,List<K>>, the size of which return the keySet.size(). But in the case of MultiMap, it will return the size of values.size() which is sum of the number of elements in entire value collection

Comment: @brainstorm: No problem. It is a bit confusing, but both `Map` and `Multimap` are defined in terms of _key-value pairs_ (also known as _entries_). In `Multimap`, `size()` == `entries().size()` == `keys().size()` == `values().size()`. The things that differ are `keySet().size()` (the number of _distinct_ keys in the multimap) and `asMap().size()` (the number of key -> collection pairs when viewing as a `Map`), which are equal to each other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Guava's API docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#size()),

**int size()**

> Returns the number of key-value pairs in this multimap. Note: this
>   method does not return the number of distinct keys in the multimap,
>   which is given by keySet().size() or asMap().size(). See the opening
>   section of the Multimap class documentation for clarification.

If you want to get the number of distinct keys, try

```
myMultimap.keySet().size()
```

Answer (score 4):

`size()` is [defined as](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#size()) the number key-value *pairs*, in your case there are 4.

Comment: so size basically returns the number of values (which is equal to key value pairs)